SuperPuTTY layout configuration
When I open my SuperPuTTY application the top three menu bars are not in the best order. They are arranged as follows:
Send Commands (The line that allows you to send a command to the terminal)
Quick Connect (The line that you put in the Host, Login, Password, and Session info)
Menu bar (Standard line with File, View, Tools, and Help)
I would love to have them revert back to what they were a few weeks ago:
Menu bar
Quick Connect
Send Commands
I've looked through all the settings and cannot find one that details it.  I rearranged the lines and tried to save the layout with no luck.  I rearranged the lines and closed the application, reopened it hoping it kept the last configuration... no luck.
I poked around the installation directory for any files that have been updated recently hoping to find an XML file to edit with no luck.  The last time a file was updated was roughly 8 months ago.
Any thoughts?

Could you include a picture perhaps, and a mockup of what you want it to look like?
